SO Discussions has a bigger UI that prevents you from knowing if a discussion already has replies
If you open any SO discussion within a Collective, for example AWS/Google Cloud, and then click on a discussion you can answer and open it, you will see a giant question box followed by a more giant answer box.
This essentially hides if people have already discussed enough on this on a bigger screen, since at first glance it appears that no discussions have taken place there.
Here's a screenshot of what I mean

As you see the majority of the screen is just the topic and a answer box, not until you scroll down and actually see the replies you would realize that there are some replies to this, otherwise in a rather "tunnel vision" sense no one has participated here.
Reducing the sizes of the text and answer boxes will allow people to browse and see discussions, which is literally what happens when you ask a SO question that is shorter in length.

Ideally, it simply wouldn't exist until you click reply and then it would show up where your reply would go.

Let's be honest, there's little need to scroll down to the replies 99% (*citation needed) of the time; just locate the flag feature and select "Not suitable for discussions".

how else will you more effectively get people to add more content without reading and voting on existing content?

In case you don't know already, the general opinion on meta is that Discussions are gigantic failures (because of many questionable design choices, not because meta is a nest of cynicism). If you look at the Discussions activity for each Collective, you'll see they're pretty much dead, so I won't exactly expect a lively discussion about UI improvements here...

I had the same impression when using trying out discussions, so I fully agree with this feature-request but unfortunately SO doesn't have a good track record on perfecting existing features. It seems a bit as if they like to start new things but after launch they kind of seem to lose interest in them, similarly to the behavior of a gold digger maybe.

@PasserBy Which isn't to say that meta is not a next of cynicism, all the same. ...Cuz it is. We're curmudgeonly!

This is very annoying indeed. The Discussions UI overall is subpar. Basically "here, have Reddit but with much crappier UI and lower quality content"... yeah that's exactly what the Internet needs...

@Lundin Especially the implementation of discussions by SO is not a proof that programming discussions wouldn't work in general. It's just not working with very limited resources and without focus on quality.

@FeRD That's "neSt of cynicism", you clod.
